# Surveys to find out which Christian denomination I am most like

Tags: denomination-survey, comparative-christianity, resource-request, internet

Are there any (free) surveys or questionnaires that I can use to determine which Christian denomination I am most like?

*I have been a Christian for many years and have preferred to read the Bible and commentaries in order to determine what I believe is right (rather than just following the teachings of one particular denomination).  With this being the case, I have not really followed one Christian denomination over another.*

Comment: You can ask a [church shopping question](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4265/what-are-the-guidelines-for-church-shopping-questions) here if you like. Just be as specific as possible. Just [edit] this one into that. I'll hold my close vote for now.

Comment: This current question form is probably okay though: [Are we allowing shopping questions or not?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/4086)

Comment: @fredsbendtheGrinch This isn't a church-shopping question. I just wanted to know if there were any surveys to find out my denomination. I was just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, here are a couple:

http://www.gotoquiz.com/which_christian_denomination_do_you_belong_to

http://www.selectsmart.com/FREE/select.php?client=christiandenom

But remember, denominations are not perfect, they are man-made, and fallible:.
The true body of Christ is made up of every born-again Christian, regardless of 'denomination'.

Comment: a good reminder

Comment: I just took both of those quizzes and wasn't impressed. If those are the best available it's unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

I wish you well in your search.

Remember one thing: If you find the perfect church, don't join it; you'll spoil it!

A second piece of advice, this time not so humorous: Attach yourself to a church where you can do the most good, in light of your God-given talents, interests, and spiritual gift-mix. (Aside: If you're not too sure about your giftedness, there are many good spiritual-gift-inventories out there, and I wouldn't be surprised if you could find a good one online by simply googling the three key words: spiritual-gift-inventory.)

Since there is a finite number of churches within your geographical region, I recommend you let your fingers do the walking in the yellow pages of a telephone directory and then call or write to a few ministers/pastors/priests/rectors, asking them to send you a doctrinal statement by email or snail mail. Many, if not most, churches have one.

Churches with websites are becoming increasingly common, too. Give 'em a call and ask for their email address, and then check 'em out that way.

Last, but perhaps most important of all, pray. Pray that God would guide your steps (Psalm 37:23). Finding a church home can be difficult, but it can also be rewarding. I've been identified with a local Christian & Missionary Alliance church now for about 17 years, and I've found a niche for service there, in spite of (or perhaps because of) its mega-church status.

In conclusion, get yourself a motto. I have a number of them. My favorite humorous one is:

> No good deed goes unpunished!

Sometimes, even within a good church, God can test you by allowing you to experience some rough waters as you rub shoulders with other fallible people like yourself. If your mindset is along the lines of

> "And let us not grow weary in well-doing, for in due season we shall reap, if we do not lose heart" (Galatians 6:9 RSV; see also 2 Thessalonians 3:13),

then I think you'll do just fine.

A more serious motto of mine is

> Born to serve!

Whenever someone (e.g., my wife, or someone at my home church) asks me to do something, I try to say cheerfully from the heart, "Born to serve."

The way I figure things, if the Son of God, the creator and sustainer of all that is came into the world not to be served, but to serve and to give his life a ransom for many, then little ol' me can do no less--well, at least the serving part (see Matthew 20:28 and Mark 10:45).

Comment: @Mathematician: You're welcome. Best wishes to you. Don